# change a href link by click on id

Tags: html

I want Change Other `<a href="?!"> <a>` tag href url my code is

```html
<a onclick=" change url with ( 'https://google.com') " > simple1 </a>
<a onclick=" change url with ( 'https://yahoo.com') " > simple2 </a>
<a onclick=" change url with ( 'https://msn.com') " > simple3 </a>

// I want to change this link

<a href="(( here must change ))" > changed url </a>
```

Comment: Please show your attempts. See [ask].

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute, `href` is an attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this code will do what you ask.

Note I delegate from a container to not have inline event handlers

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
  const tgtLink = document.getElementById('targetLink');
  document.getElementById('linkContainer').addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('a');
    if (!tgt) return; // not a link
    tgtLink.href = tgt.dataset.url;
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="linkContainer">
<a href="#" data-url="https://google.com">Simple1</a><br/>
<a href="#" data-url="https://msn.com">Simple2</a><br/>
<a href="#" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Simple3</a><br/>
</div>

<a href="#" id="targetLink">Changed</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some basic javascript to do this:

```css
function changeUrl(url) {
  // get the a element
  var changedLink=document.getElementById('changedLink');
  // change the link
  changedLink.href=url;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="changeUrl('https://google.com')">simple1</a>
<a onclick="changeUrl('https://yahoo.com')">simple2</a>
<a onclick="changeUrl('https://msn.com')">simple3</a>

<a id="changedLink" href="initial-url">changed url</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to do this.

```html
   <a onclick="changeLink('https://google.com')">simple1</a>
  <a onclick="changeLink('https://yahoo.com')">simple2</a>
  <a href="(( here must change ))" id="targetLink">changed url</a>

  <script>
    function changeLink(newURL) {
      const targetLink = document.getElementById('targetLink');
      targetLink.href = newURL;
    }
  </script>
```